Unable to select multiple objects
So I’m not sure what is going on, but I am unable to select more than one object. The first object is select is orange and then any following that is blue. I am in object mode. I tried selecting multiple in the outliner, but the same thing happened. I am trying to turn these wireframe objects back into solid objects, but it will only do it for the orange highlighted one that I selected first.
Also, while trying to fix this problem, I somehow created a display of XYZ axis for each individual object which I have no idea how to turn off.


Uncheck 'Affect only Origins' for starters! You're also in Material Preview mode rather than Solid view (top right of the toolbar). I'd suggest you share your Blend file so that we can see what else you've changed.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Thank you! I appreciate the help.

The issue with the colors is that you've selected a non-default theme "Deep Grey" where the active object is yellow but non-active selected objects are blue.  To change this back, select Edit → Preferences... from the menu, select the "Themes" panel from the list on the left, and at the top of that panel, click on the "Deep Grey" preset and change it back to "Blender Dark".
It looks like you already figured out how to get rid of the axis annotation by unchecking the "Affect Only → Origins" option, as @JohnEason had suggested.
The remaining problem is that, when multiple objects are selected, switching the viewport display from wireframe back to textured only affects the active object by default, not all selected objects, but you can change this behavior by holding down the Alt key at just the right time.
So, select all the objects in your truck that you want to change back to solid objects, open the "Object Properties" panel in the properties pane, open up the "Viewport Display", and while holding Alt, click the "Wire" selecting in the "Display As" dropdown and change it to "Textured" (the normal default).  That should fix the issue.
Technically, as long as you're holding Alt either when you click on "Wire" to change it or when you select "Textured", all selected objects will be affected by the change, but you can just hold down Alt the whole time to be safe.

To add to that, you can select all the objects at once in the viewport by dragging the mouse over them with the left button down.

Thank you! I was losing my mind. I thought I had really messed something up.
